Transmiting JSON file between ESP32 and a Flutter app
I have a ESP32 devkit V1 with a SD card module that store data in a JSON file weighting about 600kb. I want to send it to a flutter mobile app on android.

I've looked into bluetooth classic but it seems difficult to use in
flutter.
BLE is also problematic because of the file size.
Finally I looked into P2P file tranfer but from what I read, ESP32 only
support P2P between 2 ESP32.
I thought of using firebase as an
intermediate between the ESP32 and flutter but from what I've seen
the ESP32 can only send variables, not entire files.

Is there any way
I can transfer it wirelessly or is my only solution a usb cable?

Once you are doing IoT type stuff with Android, it will be hard to avoid using/writing Android Java/Kotlin code. Flutter is a UI framework, and you depend on plugins or platform-channels code to make Android hardware do what you want. Additional directions for research include are: can both the Android device and ESP32 on the same WiFi network and what existing open-source projects exist between Android and ESP32. StackOverflow works best with specific programming problems. Good luck.
